# query database for address and display it on a google map

Tags: mysql, database, maps

I have a db with addresses I need to display on a google map that would then add a marker to the map after the user has used the search form to search for the desired address. I have looked everywhere and I do not know how to link the google map to the db to show the address and display a marker. How do I connect the search form to query the db and then display it on a google map? I have researched static maps and adding markers but I cannot find how to do this. I have been searching for months and months and this is the final peice of info i need to complete this project. Can someonen please direct me or tell me how to do this? I would give my right arm for this information by now. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this API, it will return coordinates based on an address: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

After that, look here, and insert the coordinates on the map for a static map: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

If  you don't know how to do all this, I recommend doing some PHP/MySQL tutorials.